# How to pass variable from tableview to second tableview?

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, tableview, storyboard

I have a TableViewController with x rows. When the user taps on one row , i want to pass to the second tableViewController a variable that will determine which data the second tableViewController should load. How would I do that?

I am using Xcode 4.2, storyboard
here's  the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *__strong)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

    TestTable *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TestTable"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated: YES];

    detail.num = [NSString stringWithFormat:[heads objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

In "heads" i get a number which i have to pass to the second tableview,depending upon which second tableview show data. Don't know whether the last line loads "heads" in "num". Is my approach correct?
Any help/reference is appreciated

Comment: what is heads? also make your question more clear.

Comment: heads is a mutable array(containing simply integers)

Comment: cell.textLabel.text =[heads objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: `heads is a mutable array(containing simply integers)` - can we assume you mean `NSNumbers`, not just integers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *__strong)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

    TestTable *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TestTable"];

    detail.num = [[NSString stringWithFormat:[heads objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] intValue];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated: YES];
}
```

Comment: mistake in my code was i had to pass the variable before the push command which i didn't. Also please note the intValue i used in the new code.

Answer (score 2):

Give your TestTable a property for the variable you want to past, e.g.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSNumber *myNumber;
```

in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath assign it like:

```
TestTable *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TestTable"];

// this assumes that you only have one section in your table
detail.myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[heads objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated: YES];

detail.num = [NSString stringWithFormat:[heads objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

In your second table's viewcontroller, you can use the number as follows:

```
double d = [self.myNumber doubleValue];
```

Comment: Edited the answer to include the usage in the target table.